# Seeking WebGIS alternatives similar to QGIS Cloud

Tags: web-mapping, software-recommendations

Host web-maps currently through QGIS cloud and looking an alternative to QGIS cloud that allows maps to be hosted in the web securely and accessed by other parties as viewers. Have already ruled out ArcGIS Online.

Does anyone know of any good alternatives?

Comment: You could look at Astun Technology cloud ~ https://www.astuntechnology.com/cloud-products/

Answer (score -1):

Some alternatives I have heard of:

- You could acquire your own cheap VPS server on AWS or other provider and run Geonode as an application for webmapping.
- Or, something that is perhaps more easy to set up is NextGIS, and also has several plugins that connect with QGIS.
- Lastly, there is also CartoDB, but that is quite expensive when you need a subscription (there is a free educational plan) and also has its own limitations.